how to run python on iis server
i have a python script file which use DeepFace library.
everything is ok when run it in VSCode, but how to deploy the file in iis to be use it as web api?
iis link: http://localhost/face/face.py
iis return:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

i tried to add .py to iis MIME.
also tried to edit web.config file and added some handlers but nothing working
My code:
@app.route('/face_verification', methods=['POST'])
def post_example():
    result = DeepFace.verify(param1,param1)
        try:
            return (result)
        except Exception as e:
            return (e)

web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <!-- ADD THIS -->
    </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="GET, POST" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>


maybe it needs to install extra module with Python - at least in Apache you have to install mod_python or mod_wsgi (eventually old mod_fcgi) to run flask (or any Python code)

if it runs as CGI then script may have to be in subfolder bin/ (and on Linux it may need privilege executable)

better show config files.

To use Python on IIS, you might refer to https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-fastapi-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ or https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

This error should be that you did not add the cgi handler, try to follow below steps to add the python cgi:

Install the IIS CGI feature, open the control panel's Programs and Features and enable the IIS's CGI.
Open the IIS management console and click the handler mapping feature.
Add below setting:



i already did that config. and i have: @app.route('/face_verification', methods=['POST']) in my app, i need to know to call that function from POSTMAN

Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404.3 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
